# Why updating object models in Django doesn't work as expected?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This seems strange

I have the following model in Django:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, unique=True)
    validated_account = models.BooleanField(_('validated account'), blank=False, default=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

I have the following form to edit the model:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None
    
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "phone", "username"]
```

This is my view to edit the model:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated, "users:login")
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        print(form)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)

            messages.success(request, "Edition successful.")

            return redirect("dashboard:cases")

        messages.error(
            request, "Unsuccessful Edition. Invalid information.")
    else:
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        

    return render(request=request, template_name="dashboard/edit_profile.html", context={"edit_profile_form": form})
```

This is the printing result from the view call:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['DbmuCTIOAXdP96Ozrcsf3YXSCxQ1lusywgLz4OLh5FAHrjas25inxqIt0kS9syaj'], 'first_name': ['Super'], 'last_name': ['User'], 'email': ['admin@example.com'], 'phone': ['+0043328107a'], 'username': ['admin']}>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_first_name">First name:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Super" maxlength="20" required id="id_first_name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="User" maxlength="20" required id="id_last_name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_email">Email address:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="admin@example.com" maxlength="254" required id="id_email">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_phone">Phone:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" value="+0043328107" maxlength="128" required id="id_phone">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="username" value="admin" maxlength="150" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" required id="id_username">
        <br>
        <span class="helptext">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Why doesn't the resulting form contain the last letter in the phone number? In the POST request, a phone number with a letter at the end clearly appears. I would expect it to be not valid, and instead the form is valid.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `PhoneNumberField` is from `django-phonenumber-field`. If so,

**Short answer**: That's the library doing it.

**Long answer:**
The specified behaviour of html input of type `tel` is to allow almost all characters since phone numbers have varied syntax.

> Unlike the URL and Email types, the Telephone type does not enforce a particular syntax. This is intentional; in practice, telephone number fields tend to be free-form fields, because there are a wide variety of valid phone numbers.

Except for a carriage return `/r` or line feed `/n`, the input will let you type in anything, including a mixture of letters and numbers as is your case. That's why the POSTed data contains the 'invalid' character.

But you're using `PhoneNumberField` for that field, that's what's responsible for the 'unexpected' behaviour. Django forms implement `to_python` method which is responsible for converting the user html inputs into Python objects. The returned value is what's used in the form/model's `clean` method. And this is where the 'unexpected' behaviour originates.

`PhoneNumberField` overrides this `to_python` method, and when supplied a string (which is always the case with html forms), it parses the input using `phonenumbers`'s `parse` function. This is what's removing the invalid character in your bound form field's value.

Here is a demonstration
[image: phonenumbers' parse method]

You can see the `national_number` attribute has stripped off the trailing invalid characters. It does the parsing for invalid characters in between the phone number as well. The exact implementation of how it does this is explained in the `parse` function's doc string:

> """The method is quite lenient and looks for a number in the input text
> (raw input) and does not check whether the string is definitely only a
> phone number. To do this, it ignores punctuation and white-space, as
> well as any text before the number (e.g. a leading "Tel: ") and trims
> the non-number bits.  It will accept a number in any format (E164,
> national, international etc), assuming it can be interpreted with the
> defaultRegion supplied. It also attempts to convert any alpha characters
> into digits if it thinks this is a vanity number of the type "1800
> MICROSOFT".

Again, this assumes you're using `django-phonenumber-field`, if not, well, I am dammed.

Comment: That's right, I'm using that package. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the form is valid? Based on the view code you have there it will display the form again if it is not valid. If it was valid, it would be redirecting you.

Comment: Exactly. The form turns out to be valid, and it redirects me, when it should be that it is not valid in my opinion